# Radeditor removing buttons in codebehind

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, radeditor

need a little sample code please and I am working VB.net.

I am using Teleriks RadEditor throughout my website and each area has varying degrees of access and ability so with each editor I want to remove certain buttons, such as the insert media button.

An example code, very simple:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/TextEditor.ascx"%>
<dnn:TextEditor ID="txtInfo" runat="server" ChooseMode="False"
           Width="100%" />
```

In code behind, I am guessing I need to find the control and the use the ability of the variable/control to remove the buttons.

If anyone has tackled this problem, some sample code would be appreciated please?

Answer (score 0):

I completely rebuilt all buttons from ground up

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" Runat="server"
         AutoResizeHeight="true" Width="100%" >
         <Tools>
            <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Undo" ShortCut="CTRL+Z" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Redo" ShortCut="CTRL+R" />
                <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="SelectAll" ShortCut="CTRL+A" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Cut" ShortCut="CTRL+X" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Copy" ShortCut="CTRL+C" />
                <telerik:Editortool Name="Paste" ShortCut="CTRL+P" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="PasteStrip" />
                <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="LinkManager" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Unlink" />
                <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="FormatBlock" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="FontSize" />
            </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
            <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Bold" ShortCut="CTRL+B" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Italic" ShortCut="CTRL+I" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Underline" ShortCut="CTRL+U" />
                <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyLeft" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyCenter" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyRight" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyFull" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyNone" />
                <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="Indent" />
                <telerik:EditorTool name="Outdent" />
                <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertUnorderedList" />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertOrderedList" />
                <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertSymbol" />
            </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
         </Tools>
        </telerik:RadEditor>
```